# Screen Flicker on Windows 10 with Multiple Monitors

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus

On a Latitude E6530, I get a flickering screen issue only after both upgrading to windows 10 and while using a monitor. The problem doesn't appear otherwise.

Both monitors seem to be set to 60 Hz.

I tried updating my Nvidia driver, didn't work.

This occurs with more than one monitor.

Given that this occurs with the upgrade to windows 10 I'm forced to think its a driver issue, but if updating the drivers doesn't fix it I don't know what else to try.

It appears to me that the flicker only occurs on the laptop's screen and not the secondary monitor.

Edit: By switching off optimus and rebooting, installing the latest intel graphics drivers, I get no flicker. I don't like Optimus being enabled though, so I'd like a solution that doesn't involve using the intel card at all...

Answer (score 1):

On laptops Windows will always *[laptops using Nvidia GPU's, not sure about AMD]* run on the integrated GPU on the CPU, and only switch to the dedicated GPU in applications apart from that, that demand it.

You can also try going to the **Nvidia Control Panel**, and go to **Manage 3D Settings**, and set the preferred GPU to Nvidia Dedicated GPU.

Not sure if that completely answered your question though. :/

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: Boot Windows In Safe Mode.
- Step 2: Uninstall NVIDIA GPU Driver.
- Step 3: Restart Windows In Safe Mode.
- Step 4: Reinstall The Driver